# Facebook share strips og:title with "#" and "@"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, rdfa

In one of our content page, we have a Facebook share using og tags.  The page has `og:title` with content having "#" and "@". This is getting generated in the run time HTML without any issues.

This is the runtime meta tag from webpage:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Check out this awesome project, &quot;interesting title of the event &quot;, and see how we can all #interestingproject with test! @test 
 Saturday, Dec 2nd at 9:00am">
```

When this is successfully shared to Facebook, the title is displayed without "#" and "@". When I try to scrape the URL, the `og:title` shows up without "#" and "@". Tried to do a JavaScript `encodeURI` of this value. But does not help.

Tried to google as well search through Facebook docs. I could not find any explanation for this. OpenGraph documentation mentioned the value of the tags are Unicode string literals.

Does Facebook strip these characters?

Comment: _“Does facebook strip these characters?”_ - sounds like it. Probably want to prevent that users confuse this for real, “working” hashtags or mentions, or to keep the attention huggers at bay …

Comment: @misorude - Thanks for your response. I worked around the problem by avoiding those restricted characters in title field.